# Javascript namespace not defined Jeffrey Way PHP vars to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Jeffrey Way has a created a very convenient package for accessing your PHP variables in Javascript - https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer.  However, I am having a problem with this in a digitalocean production environment (works fine locally).

I have it installed in composer:

```
"require":{
    "laracasts/utilities":"dev-master"
}
```

Have it installed in app/config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
     ...
     ...
     'Laracasts\Utilities\UtilitiesServiceProvider',
 )
```

ran composer, published the config file and set the elements in the config/laracasts/utilities/config.php file

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View to Bind JavaScript Vars To
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Set this value to the name of the view (or partial) that
| you want to prepend the JavaScript variables to.
|
*/
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'layouts/partials/_footer',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JavaScript Namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, we'll add variables to the global window object.
| It's recommended that you change this to some namespace - anything.
| That way, from your JS, you may do something like `Laracasts.myVar`.
|
*/
'js_namespace' => 'MyApp'
```

];

but I am getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined" error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  It wound up being a permissions issue set on the config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is no such view `layouts/partials/_footer`. Try changing your path to be like this (use dots instead of the slashes):

`'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'layouts.partials._footer',`

That should fix your issue.

Comment: I did make the change you suggest but it still doesn't work.  I have it with backslashes locally and it works fine.